# php session auto creating non stop

Tags: php, apache, session, wamp

Alright this is so freaking weird.
I run a **Wamp server** and it is online accessible from a IP address.
The thing is that when I take a look into *D:\wamp\tmp* I can see every session file.

But even if there is no user on my website, *no one knows about it*, I can see tons of session file being created, it's filling, I wait 5 minutes and there is like 35 new session file that has been created. As long as the server run, there is new session every (random) time that are being created.

The question is simply, how is it even possible that session are being created if no one runs my page in their browser? Could it be bots, or anything like search engine that are connecting to it?

**MY SOLUTION:** 
I ended using the '**blackhole-bad-bots**'. from [perishablepress.com/blackhole-bad-bots](http://perishablepress.com/blackhole-bad-bots/) Right now I already blocked 30 of those.

Comment: Maybe check `session.auto_start` php var.

Comment: Check the `access_log` of your web server and you will see who is accessing it and what pages.

Comment: my php ini file has session.auto_start set to 0.
my access logs show me a lot of ip address, lots of them arent mine!
Thats weirds cause nobody but me should know about this and why would they be refreshing the index page non stop lol

Comment: I searched for an IP that was in my access log and found this http://cleantalk.org/blacklists/173.254.234.187
Seems like it is some spam stuff!!

Comment: Well I think the question is answered, Im subject to spam bots, and I am currently looking for a way to fix this

Comment: @Mathieu [Stop abusive bots from crawling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045705/stop-abusive-bots-from-crawling) or simple disallow anything but your IP from accessing it? If you gave that URL once to anyone you're subject to have your URL indexed elsewhere.

Comment: I ended using the 'blackhole-bad-bots'.
http://perishablepress.com/blackhole-bad-bots
Right now I already blocked 30 of those.